# Extracting a list of items from tkinter.Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I wrote the following tkinter script to understand how to add a list of data into a tkinter.Listbox widget. I discovered 2 methods for doing so.

Next, I wanted to extract the same list from the tkinter.Listbox widget. Out of the 4 different approaches, I only managed to get the 4th approach (i.e. e4) to work.

How can I get approaches e1, e2 and e3 to work? The end goal is to get the same list that was initially supplied to the tkinter.Listbox widget.

**Test Script:**

```
import tkinter as tk # Python 3 tkinter modules
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        # 1. Initialise Frame
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # Method1
        name1 = ['Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary']
        self.lb1_values = tk.StringVar(value=name1)
        self.listbox1 = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.lb1_values)

        # Method2
        self.listbox2 = tk.Listbox(self)
        name2 = ['Sarah', 'Sean', 'Mora', 'Mori', 'Mary']
        for item in name2:
            self.listbox2.insert(tk.END, item)

        self.listbox1.grid(in_=self, row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.listbox2.grid(in_=self, row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        # Extract values from listbox and covert to a list
        e1 = self.lb1_values.get()
        print('e1 = ', e1)
        print('type(e1) = ', type(e1))
        e1 = e1.strip(',')
        print('e1 = ', e1)

        e2 = self.listbox1.cget('listvariable')
        print('\ne2 = ', e2)
        print('type(e2) = ', type(e2))
        e2 = e2.split(',')
        print('e2 = ', e2)

        e3 = self.listbox2.cget('listvariable')
        print('\ne3 = ', e3)
        print('type(e3) = ', type(e3))

        e4 = self.listbox2.get(0, tk.END)
        print('\ne4 = ', e4)
        print('type(e4) = ', type(e4))
        e4 = list(e4)
        print('e4 = ', e4)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('App'), root.geometry('400x200')
    app = App(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    #root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

```
e1 =  ('Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary')
type(e1) =  <class 'str'>
e1 =  ('Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary')

e2 =  PY_VAR0
type(e2) =  <class 'str'>
e2 =  ['PY_VAR0']

e3 =  
type(e3) =  <class 'str'>

e4 =  ('Sarah', 'Sean', 'Mora', 'Mori', 'Mary')
type(e4) =  <class 'tuple'>
e4 =  ['Sarah', 'Sean', 'Mora', 'Mori', 'Mary']
```

Comment: I am AFpK right now. Would you be kind enough to provide the result of `print('type(e...` expressions?

Comment: @Nae The outputs have been appended.

Comment: `PY_VAR` is the name of the internal tcl variable, so you can rely on the `globalgetvar` function to retrive value. For example: `print(list(self.tk.globalgetvar(self.listbox1.cget('listvariable'))))`.

Comment: @CommonSense Thanks. Got it working for e2. Do you know how to resolve e1? There must be very establish and simple way to convert the string returned by e1 to a list.

Comment: Assigning a list as value to a variable class looks fundamentally wrong, does your listbox actually gets those values?

Comment: @Sun Bear, the `get` result is literally a result of the `globalgetvar` function converted to `str`, hence consider overriding this function.

Comment: @Nae I had used `StringVar` because [New Mexico Tech](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html) taught so for the `tk.Listbox` widget's `listvariable` option. `tk.Listbox` does get those values. I hope I have understood your question and New Mexico Tech instructions correctly. I am only just discovering the existence of `tk.Variable` and it's difference from `tk.StringVar`.

Comment: @SunBear That's not exactly the part I'm irritated by. `self.lb1_values = tk.StringVar(value=name1)` irritates me as `name1` is a `list` as opposed to a string which is the type it is supposed to be.

Comment: @Nae Noted. So I should have converted list `name1` to a string like  `"Peter Scotty Walter Scott Mary"`.

Comment: @SunBear I wouldn't suggest that either. Using `tk.Variable`(proposed in [Bryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626736/7032856)) is probably the best bet as Bryan Oakley is one of the, if not _the_ very, most senior programmer on the subject (that I know at least).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a `StringVar` as the target of the `listvariable` attribute. As your code shows, this causes the list to be converted to a string.

What you can do, however, is use an instance of `tk.Variable` instead. `Variable` is the base class for `StringVar`. The base implementation of `get` will not coerce the value to a string.

```
name1 = ['Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary']
self.lb1_values = tk.Variable(value=name1)
self.listbox1 = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.lb1_values)
...
e1 = self.lb1_values.get()
print('e1 = ', e1)
print('type(e1) = ', type(e1))
print('e1 = ', e1)
```

The above yields this output:

```
e1 =  ('Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary')
type(e1) =  <class 'tuple'>
e1 =  ('Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary')
```

For e2 and e3 you have to jump through an extra hoop. The `cget` method unfortunately returns the internal variable name rather than a reference to the variable object. To get the value of a variable by name you need to use the widget method `getvar`.

For example:

```
e2 = self.listbox1.cget('listvariable')
print('\ne2 = ', e2)
print('type(e2) = ', type(e2))
print('e2 = ', self.getvar(e2))
```

The above yields this output:

```
e2 =  PY_VAR0
type(e2) =  <class 'str'>
e2 =  ('Peter', 'Scotty', 'Walter', 'Scott', 'Mary')
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I had used `StringVar` because it was taught so for the [listvariable](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html) of Listbox widget. I am unable to get e3 to work following your instructions. `File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 507, in getvar
    return self.tk.getvar(name)
_tkinter.TclError: can't read "": no such variable`. Is it that I can't use `.cget('listvariable')` when supplying data to listbox via Method 2?

Comment: @SunBear The reason `e3` doesn't work is that `self.listbox2` _hasn't_ a `listvariable` as in it has the default value of `""`. When you try to use `getvar` it tries to search for an object that _isn't_.

Comment: @Nae: yes. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Am I correct to say that `self.listbox2` hasn't a `listvariable` because Method2 does not use a `listvariable' to load data into a `tk.Listbox` but instead uses the `.insert(tk.END, item)` method? If so, this means that tk.Listbox has 2 methods of storing data. In the question by @Nae, I gathered that `listvariable` is a variable class. So what type of object is used to store the data via `.insert(tk.END, item) ` method? I gather it is not a variable class since `getvar` returns `""`.

Comment: @SunBear: the data is simply stored internally by the widget. The listbox itself is the object that holds the data.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `listbox.get (0, tkinter.END)`?

Comment: @MinionJim: yes, that's the most common way to do it.

Comment: @BryanOakley Is it not worth adding this to your answer then (for others in the future)?

Comment: @MinionJim: the question didn't ask what was the best way. It asked why some ways worked and some ways didn't.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, my fault (you make a VERY good point). Just ignore me!